# Ложь о программировании или почему многие врут?

Tags: python

Данный вопрос относится ко всему программированию.
Почему не говорят правды о программировании? Почему не говорят о том, что это сложно, очень сложно? Что это непонятно? Что это не для всех?

Множество видео на YouTube, статей в интернете о том как легко стать программистом. Различные платные и бесплатные курсы, сайты с обучением, видеокурсы и много другого. И все из них утверждают, что программистом может стать каждый, это реально. В комментариях различные истории успеха: за 2 недели сделал телеграмм-бота; нашёл работу через три месяца. И все с этим согласны, что такое возможно.

У меня создаётся ощущение, что только про программирование говорят как это реально. Ни разу не слышал, чтобы говорили что математика для всех, физика для всех, литература для всех, история, философия, филология, медицина, музыка. Во всех этих сферах абсолютно нормально представление, что математика не каждому дана, биология или химия. Кто-то не понимает математику и такое есть. Кому-то сложна история. Кому-то физика со своими законами. И в каждом случае это нормально.

Но только одно программирование доступно для всех: математик, лётчик, строитель, дворник, школьник, пенсионер, взрослый и ребенок. Всем дорога открыта.

И я не понимаю почему никто не говорит, что это не для всех. Почему никто не скажет, что неважно тупой ты или умный, неважно какая у тебя работа и кто ты по специальности — это всё не определяет станешь ли ты программистом или нет. Какие же критерии для определения? Неизвестно или известно кому-то, но они не хотят сообщать.

Обычно в ответ на такое можно услышать: на самом деле тебе не интересно программирование, нет мотивации. Но как это неинтересно? Как нет мотивации?

Программирование сложно учить, оно во многом непонятно.
Я пару месяцев учу Python, но уже понимаю что я достиг предела. Я по несколько раз посмотрел и прочитал про условия, циклы, списки, генереторы, кортежи и т.д. Но по-прежнему стою на месте и нет ни малейшей предпоссылки что я сдвинусь и пойму побольше.

И это не самое ужасное. Ужасно то, что непонятно как из всего этого делать программы. Как из условий и циклов сделать полноценную программу. Смотришь как другие делают и непонятно. Вот здесь написали это, там то. Хорошо, я знаю эту команду, я знаю что она делает, я знаю что здесь цикл или условие. Но почему здесь это нужно делать. Почему? Я не понимаю.

Возможно, там слишком сложный уровень для начинающего и нужно ещё больше подучить. Начинаешь снова, и уже в который раз встречаешь if, for, while и т.д. И каждый раз одно и то же.

Думаешь порешать задачи, задачи для самых тупых и начинающих. Но оказывается хороших задач нет или их 1-2. Да и просто сложно найти. Там либо непонятно условие и непонятно, что требуется от тебя. Без понимания условия и вопроса, невозможно решить задачу, как бы кто ни пробовал.

Но даже, если понятно условие и что требуется найти, как понять что я решил правильно. Нет ответов. И в данный момент единственные задачи которые я могу решать это либо самостоятельно придуманные (их очень мало) или из категории:  вводится двухзначное число, вывести каждую цифру числа по отдельности. Но таких задач мало (только 1 такую нашёл). Все остальные непонятно что требуется найти, сделать и какой ответ должен быть и почему именно такой ответ.

Можно спрашивать на форумах, например здесь, если что-то непонятно. Но как спросить, если не знаешь что спрашивать?

Подытоживая, я могу с уверенностью сказать, что программирование не для всех, вокруг его много лжи, заблуждений. И я понимаю, что мне никто не даст ответ на эти вопросы (но ОЧЕНЬ бы хотелось их получить). Найдутся те, кто смог всего за три месяца стать Python  Junior, не понимая что им это дано, как с музыкой (без музыкального слуха, музыкантом никогда не станешь, а слух или есть, или нет).

P.s. Я продолжу сидеть над Pythоn. Пытаться понять и что-то сделать на нём, но уже нет надежд сделать игру или хотя бы что-то (приложение к примеру, калькулятор тот же самый). Буду пробовать придумать для себя понятные задачи и пытаться решить их. Но как правило такие задачи лёгкие. Возможно буду просить помощи с решением задач или проблем, если буду знать что спрашивать. Но скорей всего это будет просто бессмысленный и бесконечный процесс и путь в никуда.

Comment: Очевидно ведь, что если начнут говорить, что программирование не для всех - "волшебные" курсы перестанут продаваться

Comment: Не думай много - делай!

Comment: Современное общество пронизано показной гуманностью и политкорректностью. Никто не говорит, что люди бывают разные, назвать дурака дураком означает навлечь на себя гнев праведников, я уже не говорю о бросании щенков в воду и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: тут как в жизни, изучай охоту, собирая корешки, но победит скотоводство, а далее селекция и генетика. разницу уровней понимания жизни видите? ждите от себя т.н. прорыва сознания. практикуйте. изучайте на гитхабе успешные проекты, как написано. что делают, почему они нужны обществу.

Comment: "Я пару месяцев учу Python..." - заходи через год - поговорим. З.Ы. Рекомендую нормальные курсы (за деньги, у того же яндекса, например), потому что учиться надо у драйвовых людей, чтобы голова болела, а не на форумах, видосиках ютюба - все это "печеньки к чаю"

Comment: Потому что бизнес, ничего личного

Comment: Японский язык не для всех. Кого ни возьми, не знают они японского. Ни писать, ни читать не умеют. Учить сложно: начинает сотня, что-то промычать может один. Тут всё ясно?. И наоборот, если вы родились в Японии, вы будете знать японский язык. Программирование кажется сложным, потому что требуется преодолеть огромный барьер сродни языковому. Это навык, он тренируется у любого. Скорость разная, но тренируется. Когда в голове накопится некоторый минимум, станет легче. Можно будет продолжать, если захочется.

Comment: Не знаю как здесь ответить каждому, поэтому напишу общий для всех ответ.

Comment: Alexander Chernin, если не забуду, то зайду через год. Чтобы пойти на платные курсы нужны деньги, а их нет. Поэтому не вариант. И какая гарантия, что они помогут, если и бесплатно не научился? А чтобы голова болела нужны задачи.

Comment: Stanislav Volodarsky, да, японский язык не для всех, и это нормально. Кому-то языки не даются, кому-то английский легче и европейские, а кому-то японский с азбуками и иероглифами даётся легко. Программирование не кажется сложным, оно не каждому дано и сравнение с японским не подходит как видно. Не понимаю про какой навык сказано? О минимуме: какой он? где его предел? Сколько надо посмотреть, прочитать кортежи, функции, словари, циклы, чтобы этот минимум появился? И стало понятно как писать программы? И в конце: есть разница между лень учить, сложно учить, но возможно и не для всех.

Comment: Павел, я понимаю авторов курсов или популярных блоггеров, что рекламируют эти курсы, там есть выгода. Но какая выгода у тех, кто не рекламирует, не продаёт и просто непопулярный. avp, про политкорректность и гумманость согласен и знаю про это. Но, если ответ на вопрося то грустно.